# How to plot two lines by factor in a trellis graph?

Tags: r, ggplot2, lattice, trellis

Define:

```
df <- data.frame(
        line1 = rep(seq(1,5,by=1),2), 
        line2 = rep(seq(2,6,by=1),2),
        index = rep(seq(1,5,by=1),2),
        factor=rep(c("a","b"),each=5))
```

where `line1` and `line2` are two variables, say height and weight.

This is the simple style I would want for each panel (I would also like to change size of point markers, but not use how):

```
plot(df$line1[df$factor=="a"], type = "o", ylim=c(0,6))
lines(df$line2[df$factor=="a"], type = "o", lty=2, pch=0)
```

When I try this:

```
library(lattice)
xyplot(c(line1,line2)~index|factor,data=df,type="o")
```

the program treats all points as if they belong on one line.

In addition I am not sure how to feed in the arguments for plot style to get the desired results.

PS1. Surprisingly I have Googled around and found lots of scatter plots (with linear fits, densities, etc.) and histogram examples of trellis graphs, but not one of the simple thing I am trying to do.

PS2. I would like to tag this question `trellis` but do not have reputation points to create tag.  Any volunteers?

Comment: tag is created. I also changed trellis to lattice, as the library is called lattice

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is actually very simple. Instead of combining line1 and line2 to a vector, just use the extended formula interface of xyplot :

```
xyplot(line1+line2~index|factor,data=df,type="o")
```

gives :

[image]

Check also `?xyplot` read through the heaps of text and play a bit with the examples there. You'll find out how to customize this with titles, legends and the likes.

As you labeled `ggplot2` as well, this is one possibility of getting it done with that package :

```
require(ggplot2)
require(reshape)
df2 <- melt(df,id=c("index","factor"))

qplot(index,value,variable,facets = .~factor ,
          data=df2,geom="line",colour=variable)
```

Gives :

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  I did skim read through the "heaps of text" in `?xyplot`.  Unfortunately the simple things were lost along the way...

Comment: Thanks for `ggplot` example.  When I looked at the Hadley's web page for package I got the impression I would have to reshape the data.  I found that surprising:  That is not how data is typically stored.  Also, colors look nice, but for working papers we are typically limited to B&W.  Would be nice to be able to set B&W constraints so the color palette is only shades of grey.

Comment: @Fred : use the `col=c("black","grey")` argument in xyplot or use `+ scale_colour_manual(values=c("black","grey"))` after qplot. See - again - the help files. For xyplot, you might want to look at `?panel.xyplot` as well.

Comment: as for reshaping the data: yes, you do have to reshape the data, but Hadley provides tools that make it easy.  If you are going to use black and grey lines you may want to use `+theme_bw()` ...

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you can melt the data and use `group`:

```
library(reshape)
df2 <- melt(df,id.var=3:4)
xyplot(value~index|factor,data=df2,type="o",group=variable)
```